# WindowsAzure.Storage using C# mono

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, mono

Im trying to connect and download from AzureStorage blob which I manage to do using windows while writing in C#.

While working on linux however Im missing :
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

I've been adviced to use https://github.com/richorama/azure-sdk-for-mono but I cant get it to compile

If anyone have managed to do this all advice is appriciated. Basicly what Im asking is a way to be able to use WindowsAzure.Storage in my code or anything that is equivalent.

Please take in consideration that Im not experienced with Windows azure in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the WindowsAzure.Storage DLL dependencies in your app in order to use them.  You would then be able to use them without using the richorama SDK; it may be that it is not compiling because of the missing dependencies.  So you will need to get hold of these DLLs.

These are distributed through the NuGet package manager.  NuGet will grab the packages from Microsoft and add the dependencies to your project.  There may be a NuGet add-in/extension for your IDE - if you are using the MonoDevelop IDE, you will find instructions on how to install NuGet [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481002/how-to-install-nuget-addin-for-monodevelop).

Alternatively, there is a command line NuGet tool that you can use to grab the WindowsAzure packages.  This you will find on the NuGet downloads page [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget).  Hope this helps!